# Kivy Hexagonal Widgets

Tags: kivy

In Kivy, I understand how to make the default widgets, but I was wondering if there is any guidance someone can give me for attempting to make widgets of different shapes, such as hexagonal. I can find nothing about this on the documentation or here on stack exchange.

Comment: What does it mean to you to have a hexagonal widget?

Comment: There's a guy who gave a talk about making games with hexagonal tiles, but didn't go into the code much. He mentions that you can use maybe KivEnt or Tiled to work with it? Maybe this is a starting point for you. Go to 20:50 in the video (or just watch the whole thing if you want!) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hM9qbW8-roE